# How to use Rails respond_with with a create action and javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been reading about respond_with. and used it before in a couple of tutorials but dont really think I understand it fully.

The functionality I am trying to implement right now  is this: I have a list of items of class Article, and each of them has a link to the create Favorite action. When the user clicks on it  it the favorite instance is created and the user is redirected to the home page. I want this to work with AJAX without a page refresh, and execute some JavaScript on the article item to let the user know it's been favourited successfully. I've used the :remote => true attribute in the relevant link, so the action is executing remotely without problem, but I am a bit stuck on how to execute the action's .js.erb file.

I've done the following in the controller:

```
class FavouritesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate
respond_to :html, :js


  def create
    @article = Article.find_by_id(params[:article_id])
    current_user.Favourites.create(:article => @article)
    redirect_to root_path 
  end
```

The problem is, I dont know what parameter should i pass to respond_with. I've tried replacing the redirect with both respond_with @article, and respond_with without parameters, and while both of them work (the create.js.erb is called), I dont understand why...

I dont want to 'respond_with' anything, but only that when the action is executed via javascript, the create.js.erb gets called. Can anyone explain a) why does respond_with work anyway whatever I pass to it, and b) what is the right way to do this?

BTW, I am using Rails 3.0

EDIT:  I understand it better if I use respond_to like in the following code, but I would like to understand respond_with better.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  format.js
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question several times trying to solve a similar problem. It turns out my controller wasn't inferring the format as I assumed it would from the content type or the fact that it's an xhr request.

In any case, it worked when I switched from this:

```
contacts_path
```

To this:

```
contacts_path format: :json
```

I didn't care for that per se, so I changed my ajax call to include the dataType option like this (per [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({url: contactUrl, type: 'POST', data: data, dataType: 'json' });
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Oalo  go through the link below, it concisely explains the respond_with and respond_to. It lists all the options that you can pass to respond_with

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with

Hope this answers your query

Comment: Actually, that blog post is the one I read just before asking  this. While it is very good and helps me understand the subject better, it doesnt help me with this specific problem